# SharePoint 2013 Developement - adding fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

How to add the following fields:

1. Courier origin location: list of country (scrollable)
2. Courier destination location: list of countries (scrolable) - destination will be display/mention, omly if it is currently available.

Comment: Where are you trying to add them and how? By fields do you mean columns in a list?

Comment: If this is supposed to be a column, You need to choose Managed Metadata and set the termset available for your columns